# Implementing model filter

Tags: ember.js, model, filtering

I have set up the following scaffolding for my Ember application.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('coaches', function() {
        this.resource('coach', {path: "/:person_id"});
    });
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    fname: DS.attr('string')
    ,lname: DS.attr('string')
    ,sport: DS.attr('string')
    ,bio: DS.attr('string')
    ,coach: DS.attr('boolean')
    ,athlete: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Person.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 10
        ,fname: 'Jonny'
        ,lname: 'Batman'
        ,sport: 'Couch Luge'
        ,bio: 'Blah, blah, blah'
        ,coach: true
        ,athlete: true
    }
    ,{
        id: 11
        ,fname: 'Jimmy'
        ,lname: 'Falcon'
        ,sport: 'Cycling'
        ,bio: 'Yada, yada, yada'
        ,coach: false
        ,athlete: true
    }
];
```

I am trying to set up a route to filter the person model and return only coaches. Just to make sure I can access the data, I have simply used a findAll on the person model.

```
App.CoachesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('person');
    }
});
```

Now though, I am trying to implement the filter method detailed on the bottom of the [Ember.js Models - FAQ](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/) page.

```
App.CoachesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var store = this.store;
        return store.filter('coaches', { coach: true }, function(coaches) {
            return coaches.get('isCoach');
        });
    }
});
```

The coaches route is not working at all with the new route implemented and the old one commented out. I am using the Ember Chrome extension and when using the filter route the console responds with, `Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for 'coaches'`. Apparently the route is not working, specifically the model. No kidding, right? What am I missing in my filter model route?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is spot on-  there is no `CoachModel`.  I think you need to do this:

```
App.CoachesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var store = this.store;
        return store.filter('person', { coach: true }, function(coaches) {
            return coaches.get('isCoach');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Steve, first off. Thank you for your time to look at this. Obviously I have been looking at the code for too long. Thank you for catching the need to reference the `'person'` model. Now though, this is tossing another error at me.

`Error while loading route: Error: Assertion Failed: Not implemented: You must override the DS.FixtureAdapter::queryFixtures method to support querying the fixture store.` Is there a better method to use for filtering? This seems overly difficult.

Comment: That is correct.  The `FixtureAdapter` does not support queries.  I assume you will replace your fixtures with a real server at some point?  Otherwise, you can extend `FixtureAdapter` with your own adapter and implement `findQuery()`.  If my answer fixed your first problem, thank you for "accepting" it as a correct answer.

Comment: So after doing some more research, if I want to do filtering on the client side, I need to do it in the Controller, is this correct?